# how hide if using <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}> in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to hide my bottom menu on another screen but it's not working [code of tab screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwVAE.png)

and here I want to hide the menu tab [where want to hide bottom menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7IOX.png)

Comment: Which version of react navigation you are using? The property no longer exists in 6.x.

Docs: You can achieve the same behavior by specifying tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } in options.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.